# Clean up a string read in from a file python

Tags: python, file-io

I'm trying to read in a data file with a load of lines of values and associated errors in it, e.g.:

```
(-5.63150902306 +/- 0.549562002684) * (9.62647766508 +/- 1.00395610402)
(5.92097311289 +/- 0.79652553075) * (5.62917665811 +/- 0.772898764928) / (3.2342 +/- 2.4235)
```

I've successfully read in the 'segments' using the following:

```
FileSegments = [lin.split( ) for line in File.readlines()]
```

But I'd also like to remove the curly braces '(' ')' at the same time...I've tried

```
FileSegments = str([lin.split( ) for line in File.readlines()]).translate(None, ')(')
```

But that randomly return just `[` when I try and print it!

Answer (score 1):

You just had the order a bit mixed (also no need for `File.readlines()`

```
[line.translate(None, ')(').split() for line in File]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do something along these lines:

```
st='''\
(-5.63150902306 +/- 0.549562002684) * (9.62647766508 +/- 1.00395610402)
(5.92097311289 +/- 0.79652553075) * (5.62917665811 +/- 0.772898764928) / (3.2342 +/- 2.4235)'''

for line in st.splitlines():
    print 'line:',line
    print line.replace('(','').replace(')','')
```

Prints:

```
line: (-5.63150902306 +/- 0.549562002684) * (9.62647766508 +/- 1.00395610402)
-5.63150902306 +/- 0.549562002684 * 9.62647766508 +/- 1.00395610402
line: (5.92097311289 +/- 0.79652553075) * (5.62917665811 +/- 0.772898764928) / (3.2342 +/- 2.4235)
5.92097311289 +/- 0.79652553075 * 5.62917665811 +/- 0.772898764928 / 3.2342 +/- 2.4235
```

Answer (score 0):

If you'd like to replace parentheses, you can simply call `.replace()` on a string.

```
file_segments = [line.replace('(','').replace(')','').split() for line in fh.readlines()]
```

For more information on `replace`, see [String Replace](http://docs.python.org/2/library/string.html#string.replace).

You can also use `re.sub()`

```
file_segments = [re.sub('[\(|\)]','', line).split() for line in fh.readlines()]
```

But note that this is more intensive than just `.split()`.

See [re.sub](http://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html#re.sub) for more information.